# Copy only the headers of a csv file into a new file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am looking to copy only the first row(headers) of a csv file as row in a new file.

I currently have this piece of code which transposes the entire file and writes it into a new file.

But my requirement is only to have the headers of a csv file into another skipping the first row entirely.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('Cars.csv', header=None).T.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: pass `nrows=1` to `read_csv`.

Comment: `.iloc[0]` or `.columns()` without the header=None would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the headers (first row) much more efficiently without pandas:

```
with open("Cars.csv", 'r') as fid:
    header_list = fid.readline().strip().split(",")

with open("out.csv", 'w') as fid:
    fid.write("\n")
    fid.write("\n".join(header_list))
```

Comment: Apologies I wanted them the headers in a column in a new file. I wrote rows by mistake. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: changed it so now the code is reading the first line out of "cars.csv" and writing that line into "out.csv"

Comment: I am getting an error fid.write(header_line) io. UnsupportedOperation : not writeable error

Comment: Just one last thing currently I am reading my data in row. Can it be re- arranged into columns please

Comment: You got that error because I forgot the "w" when opening the second file. Thanks for the edit! What do you mean by "No Company Car Model"?

Comment: Can my headers be arranged into a single column. What I mean is can it be arranged in a manner that all the headers appear in column A starting from A2

Comment: So you'll just need to split the string into a list, then rejoin it with newline characters. Then to get it to start at A2 instead of A1, you'll need to put in a newline into the file before we put our string in.